# SQLDataReader with an empty Read after ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

Please help correct my thinking, I suspect it is either an obvious mistake or a misunderstanding in how to read from a stored procedure.

I am trying to get c# to call a stored procedure and return multiple rows. It works fine for IDs with a single instance if I remove the reader and use a

```
res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but in the code below the while part is just skipped and I cannot see why. I have been playing with the code for a while and not having any luck. The field count is zero but there is data in the table?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.ReadFromArchive", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000; //This should be the max timeout.
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArchiveID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = AD.ArchiveID;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocsKEY", SqlDbType.Char, 36).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocsDateKey", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocumentType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                  
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OperationType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                   

            try
            {                                                        
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    AD.AddDocKey((string)cmd.Parameters["@DocsKEY"].Value);
                    AD.AddDateKey((DateTime)cmd.Parameters["@DocsDateKey"].Value);
                    AD.AddDocument((string)cmd.Parameters["@DocumentType"].Value);
                    AD.AddOpType((string)cmd.Parameters["@OperationType"].Value);
                }

                AD.RTKD = res;
                AD.RTMSG = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AD.RTMSG = ex.ToString();
                Logger.LogError("1. Error with executing dbo.ReadFromArchive Stored Procedure", ex);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AD.RTMSG = ex.ToString();
        Logger.LogError("Error setting up dbo.ReadFromArchive Stored Procedure :", ex);
    }
}

return AD;
```

The Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadFromArchive]
(

@ArchiveID      CHAR(36)        ,
@DocsKEY        CHAR(36)        OUT,
@DocsDateKey    DATETIME        OUT,
@DocumentType   VARCHAR(100)    OUT,
@OperationType  VARCHAR(30)     OUT

)
AS
BEGIN

Select @DocsKEY         = DocsKEY       from     dbo.ArchiveData where  ArchiveID = @ArchiveID          
Select @DocsDateKey     = DocsDateKey   from     dbo.ArchiveData where  ArchiveID = @ArchiveID              
Select @DocumentType    = DocumentType  from     dbo.ArchiveData where  ArchiveID = @ArchiveID 
Select @OperationType   = OperationType from     dbo.ArchiveData where  ArchiveID = @ArchiveID 

END
```

The key I give it(ArchiveID) returns two seperate values when I query the SQL directly without the stored procedure. If I remove the reader read I get a single value out without problem. Now I need to make it iterate because the database will have many values per ID.

No error is thrown it just doesn't give any data back. My understanding is the reader should loop over every row, why is it not? How do I fix this?

Comment: why do you want to go for four selects? instead you could take it in a table and return the same to C#

Comment: Is SP moddification possible? Do any other components/systems depend on it?

Comment: Yes you can modify the SP I am the original author and currently it is only used one other place in the code. I need return one, return many, and return all that match two parameters. The primary key is two paramaters ArchiveID and DocumentType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify you SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadFromArchive]
(

@ArchiveID      CHAR(36)   

)
AS
BEGIN

Select DocsKEY, DocsDateKey,DocumentType   ,OperationType  from     dbo.ArchiveData where  ArchiveID = @ArchiveID   

END
```

And then you can fetch the columns inside the while loop as follows

```
reader["reader"].ToString();
```

Comment: @st4hoo He's right though isn't he? In the current setup with `out` parameters only one value per parameter is returned. The OP wants to read multiple rows returned from a SP, which requires a different setup, such as this, where the parameters become columns

Comment: If the database has many values per Id then you can not take them in a @variable, can you?

Comment: @Me.Name: **Maybe** he is right. It depends on answer to the question: "Is SP modiffication possible?".

Comment: @st4hoo Agreed, but if not, his query of `Now I need to make it iterate because the database will have many values per ID.` is not possible with the current sp and modification of the code to using a reader superfluous.

Comment: @Mohamed: Of course you can, you may merge them in single value using some separator or returning XML for example. I'm not saying that this makes sence in this context, however it is technically possible...

Comment: I think this conversation has merit. So the out will only return one value are you sure of that? Is there a way to use the OUT statement with multiple values or is it inherantly only for one? The a select statements return multiple values.

Comment: @JonathanP The out parameter will return one value, which is also demonstrated by the need to close the reader before the values can be read: they are the last return values and not per returned row. Although in theory it would be possible to concatenate the values, return those in the parameter, and split them again in code, that would require altering the stored procedure, in which case imho it's far easer to follow Mohameds example and have the stored procedure return a table, which can be read in a reader (or DataTable)

Comment: Agreed, the issue is that OUT is limited to one return value. I duplicated the original and the reader is working now. Many thanks @Mohamed

If anyone knows how to get OUT to return multiple values I would be interested in that, otherwise I will modify my SP and fix it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong, you are not reading data from the `reader`:

It should be something like that in the while loop:

```
AD.AddDocKey(reader["DocsKEY"].ToString());
```

**UPDATE**:

I haven't noticed `OUT` parameter in the Store Procedure.

Here is MSDN reference on [**Using a DataReader to Process the RETURN Value and OUTPUT Parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971497).

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
reader.Close();

AD.AddDocKey((string)cmd.Parameters["@DocsKEY"].Value);
AD.AddDateKey((DateTime)cmd.Parameters["@DocsDateKey"].Value);
AD.AddDocument((string)cmd.Parameters["@DocumentType"].Value);
AD.AddOpType((string)cmd.Parameters["@OperationType"].Value);
AD.RTKD = res;
AD.RTMSG = "";
```

Comment: No. I haven't noticed the `OUT` parameter in SP.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get output parameters value before closing `SqlDataReader`. Here is corresponding [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308621).